# Initialize final variable in two constructors

Tags: java, constructor, dry

I have two variables. And should make two constructors.

```
 private int size;
 final private Class clazz;
```

First:

```
public SomeConstr(int size) {
    if (size <= 0) {
        this.size = 0;
        IllegalArgumentException argumentException = new IllegalArgumentException();
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "", argumentException);
        throw argumentException;
    }
    else
        this.size = size;

    this.clazz = Device.class;       
    }
}
```

Second:

```
public ComeConstrSecond(int size, Class clazz) {
   this(size);

   if (clazz == null || !Device.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
         logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "");
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
   }

   this.clazz = clazz; 
 }
```

When I initialise `this.clazz = clazz` in the second constructor, I have a problem like `have been assigned to`. How correct write initialisation for `clazz` if I must use `this(size)`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Chain your constructors the other way round - from the one with partial information to the one with all the information:

```
public SomeConstr(int size) {
   this(size, Device.class);
}

public SomeConstr(int size, Class clazz) {
    if (size <= 0) {
        IllegalArgumentException argumentException = new IllegalArgumentException();
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "", argumentException);
        throw argumentException;
    }
    if (clazz == null || !Device.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    this.size = size;
    this.clazz = clazz;
}
```